# How to properly extend ObservableCollection<T> with Search?

Tags: c#

The following Search() function works for searching ObservableCollection<MyClassA> but this breaks if I want to search ObservableCollection<MyClassB> or ObservableCollection<MyClassC>.  I can't overload Search() to handle different types.  Is there a way to accomplish this by removing "where T: MyClassA" and handle types specific search with a switch-case?  Is there a better way? I also suspect there is a more efficient and/or elegant solution to copying the matching elements from one collection to another.

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> Search<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> 
    collection, string searchString) where T: MyClassA
{
    if (collection == null) {return null;}
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString)) {return null;}
    IEnumerable<T> searchResult = collection.Where(x => 
         x.Name.Contains(searchString) ||
         x.Description.Contains(searchString));

    ObservableCollection<T> resultCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    foreach (T item in searchResult)
    {
        resultCollection.Add(item);
    }
    return resultCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass in a predicate instead of a search string:

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> Search<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    if (collection == null) {return null;}
    IEnumerable<T> searchResult = collection.Where(predicate);

    ObservableCollection<T> resultCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    foreach (T item in searchResult)
    {
        resultCollection.Add(item);
    }
    return resultCollection;
}
```

and then call it as:

```
BuildObservableA().Search(myA => myA.Name.Contains(searchString) || myA.Description.Contains(searchString));
BuildObservableB().Search(myB => my.Manufacturer.Contains(searchString) || ...);
```

This encapsulates the searching logic nicely while leaving it up to the caller to define exactly which elements they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If `MyClassA` and `MyClassB` both have properties `Name` and `Description` then use an interface.

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Destination{get;set;}
}
```

then

```
public class MyClassA : IMyClass
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Destination{get;set;}
}

public class MyClassB : IMyClass
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Destination{get;set;}
    public string SomethingElse{get;set;}
}
```

and

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> Search<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> 
    collection, string searchString) where T: IMyClass
{
    if (collection == null) {return null;}
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString)) {return null;}
    IEnumerable<T> searchResult = collection.Where(x => 
         x.Name.Contains(searchString) ||
         x.Description.Contains(searchString));

    ObservableCollection<T> resultCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    foreach (T item in searchResult)
    {
        resultCollection.Add(item);
    }
    return resultCollection;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution if MyClassA and MyClassB both have properties Name and Description but let's assume they do not.  For example MyClassA could be a stand in for "Class Subnet" with a "string CIDR" property; and MyClassB could be a stand in for "Class Host" with "string IpAddress" and "string MacAddress" properties.

Answer (score 0):

I devised a solution that uses a switch based on the type; where there is a specific case to handle search for each type.

```
class MyClassA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class MyClassB
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Part { get; set; }
}
public static ObservableCollection<T> Search<T>(this 
    ObservableCollection<T> collection, string searchString)
    {
        if (collection == null) { return null; }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString)) { return null;}

        ObservableCollection<T> resultCollection 
            = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        switch (collection)
        {
            case ObservableCollection<MyClassA> aCollection:
                resultCollection = aCollection.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString) ||
                                                          x.Description.Contains(searchString)).ToObservableCollection()
                                                          as ObservableCollection<T>;
                break;
            case ObservableCollection<MyClassB> bCollection:
                resultCollection = bCollection.Where(x => x.Manufacturer.Contains(searchString) ||
                                                          x.Model.Contains(searchString) ||
                                                          x.Part.Contains(searchString)).ToObservableCollection() 
                                                          as ObservableCollection<T>;
                break;
        }
        return resultCollection;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        foreach (T item in source) collection.Add(item);
        return collection;
    }
```